# How to resize an image by saving the resized version under a new name?

Tags: linux, bash, resize, imagemagick-convert

Thanks for being a part of this amazing community.
Here I've been fighting with my script and looks like I need a hint.

I have the following file structure:

> Mother_Directory/
>   ./child1_Directory
>     file1.jpg
>     file2.JPG
>     file3.jpg
>   ./child2_Directory
>     file1.jpg
>     file2.JPG
>     file3.jpg
>   ./child3_Directory
>     file1.jpg 
>     file2.JPG 
>     file3.jpg

Now I want to use `imagemagick`'s convert function to do all sorts of things (say resize) on these files in the child directories and save them in `Mother_Directory_2/`  (which is on an external hard drive) under a new name.
e.g. `external_HD_path/Mother_Directory_2/child2_Directory/resized_file1.jpg`.

Here is my code:

```
for f in `find . -name "*.*"`; do convert $f -resize 50% ../Mother_Directory_2/$f; done
```

this one was supposed to save the new files in `../Mother_Directory_2/`,
but no luck (even without name-change logic). I tend to believe that what I'm trying to achieve is something trivial but I've no idea where to look for a hint. Is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: Do the child directories exist under `Mother_Directory_2`? And could you possibly provide a problem description: i.e. what *exactly* is happening, and how does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: 1. I can create the child folders by just doing mkdir in the Mother_D_2/ with the names taken from the original Mother_D/

2. now the question is how to put the resized photos to the same named folders under Mother_d_2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that many people search for this solution here i would like to post the easiest solution i've managed to write based on all the comments and posts i've went through.

**step 1.** create  all the folders in the new Mother_Directory_2 (get the names of the folders from the original Mother_Directory)

```
for d in */ ; do mkdir ~/Desktop/Mother_Directory_2/$d; done
```

**step 2.** 
2.1.get the child directory names by using  
    parentname="$(basename "$(dirname "$f")")"  
2.2. get the filenames by using 
    base=$(basename "$f") 
3.3 Run the script below (cd Mother_Directory)

```
for f in `find . -name "*.*"`; do base=$(basename "$f") ; parentname="$(basename "$(dirname "$f")")"; convert -resize 1000x1000  ./$parentname/$base ../Mother_Directory_2/$parentname/resize_$base; done
```

hope this would be helpful - if you are a Bash specialist please suggest a more efficient way of doing the same. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is with the way you are using $f in the destination directory. The $f usually will contain the full path of the file that is being converted. Instead you can try using "basename" in the script.

```
for f in `find . -name "*.*"`; do base=$(basename "$f") ; convert $f -resize 50% ../Mother_Directory_2/$base; done
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It solves the second part of the problem, but how do i put the new files into correct directories i.e. ./child1_Directory

Mother_Directory_2/
./child1_Directory
resized_file1.jpg

Comment: ok one can get the parent name like this parentname="$(basename "$(dirname "$f")")" will try to get it working